# send message to topic based on message key using kafka streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to be able to send all records in a Kafkastream to a different topic based on the key of the message key.
Ex. A stream in Kafka contains name as key and record as value. I want to fan out these records to different topic based on the key of the record

data : (jhon -> {jhonsRecord}),(sean -> {seansRecord}),(mary -> {marysRecord}),(jhon -> {jhonsRecord2}),
expected

- topic1 :name: jhon ->(jhon -> {jhonsRecord}),(jhon -> {jhonsRecord2})
- topic2 :sean-> (sean -> {seansRecord})
- topic3 :mary -> (mary -> {marysRecord})

Below is the way I am doing this right now, but since the list of names is hudge this is slow. Plus even if there are records a few names, I need to traverse the entire list  Please suggest a fix

```
    for( String name : names )
    {
        recordsByName.filterNot(( k, v ) -> k.equalsIgnoreCase(name)).to(name);
    }
```

Comment: Note: This will potentially end up with a bunch of topics (with default settings). What is the use case here?

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for pointing that out, but that's the intention here. there are 100s of records per name and each of them needs to be processed, aggregated individually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use `KStream::to(final TopicNameExtractor<K, V> topicExtractor)` function. It gives you ability to calculate name of the topic for each message.

Sample code:

```java
final KStream<String, String> stream = ???;
stream.to((key, value, recordContext) -> key);
```

Comment: Assuming there isn't anything left to do with the output topics, I like this much better than my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [`KStream#branch`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#branch-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Predicate...-).

Following is untested, but it shows the general idea

```
// get a list of predicates to branch a topic on
final List<String> names = Arrays.asList("jhon", "sean", "mary");
final Predicate[] predicates = names.stream()
    .map((Function<String, Predicate<String, Object>>) n -> (s, o) -> s.equals(n))
    .toArray(Predicate[]::new);

// example input
final KStream<Object, Object> stream = new StreamsBuilder().stream("names");

// split the topic
KStream<String, Object>[] branches = stream.branch(predicates);
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    branches[i].to(names.get(i));
}

// KStream branches[0] contains all records whose keys are "jhon"
// KStream branches[1] contains all records whose keys are "sean"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate aggregate data for each user, you don't need to write to a separate topic per user. You'd be better off writing an aggregate on the source stream. This way you won't end up with one topic per key, but you can still run operations on each user independently.

```
Serde<UserRecord> recordSerde = ...
KStream<Stream, UserAggregate> aggregateByName = recordsByName
   .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), recordSerde))
   .aggregate(...)
   .toStream()
```

See https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#aggregating for details

This approach will scale to millions of users, someone you won't currently be able to achieve with the one topic per user approach.

Comment: That's a good thought one cavitate here is that KPIs needs to be run at both aggregated and raw data. so at any point, I may need to access user's raw data and aggregated data. ex one job might need to look at single users raw data and another job needs to look at aggregated data for a single user.

Comment: That's still possible. In the case above, you can write the aggregated results out to another topic, but the original topic with raw data is still available to read by any other consumer. You can even do this within the same Kafka Streams application where you have several different transforms running off the same source topic. In practice, Kafka Streams will read each of your input messages once and pass them to each of these separate transforms one at a time in sequence.

Comment: Yes you are right the both raw and aggregated data will be available in just 2 topics, but when I want to see the data only for one specific user, I do not have any options but to subscribe for everything and filter records for that user. Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: that's correct. Kafka just treats every message as a bucket of bytes, so any filtered will need to be done at the consumer level. If you only want records for a given user directly from Kafka, you'll need to separate them out in a separate topic.